# Objective-C ref count and autorelease

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Hey guys, suppose the following code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
//[...]
    Rectangle* myRect  = [[Rectangle alloc] init];

    Vector2* newOrigin = [[[Vector2 alloc] init] autorelease]; // ref count 1

    [newOrigin setX: 50.0f];
    [myRect setOrigin: newOrigin];    // ref count 2

    [myRect.origin setXY: 25.0f :100.0f]; // ref count goes to 3... why ?

    [myRect release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Rectangle's origin is declared as a (retain) synthesized property.
Just wondering 2 things:

1. Why does ref count goes to 3 when using the getter accessor of Rectangle's origin? Am I doing something wrong ?
2. With a ref count of 3, I don't understand how this snippet of code cannot leak. Calling release on myRect will make it go down to 2 since I call release on the origin in dealloc(). But then, when does autorelease take effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does ref count goes to 3 when
>   using the getter accessor of
>   Rectangle's origin?

Because your @property is declared as `atomic` (the default) and, thus, the synthesized getter retains and then autoreleases the return value.

> Am I doing something wrong ?

Yes.  You are studying absolute retain counts.

The absolute retain counts of any object is quite thoroughly useless to consider.  You only care about deltas;  if you cause the retain count to increase, you must cause it to decrease.

> With a ref count of 3, I don't
>   understand how this snippet of code
>   cannot leak. Calling release on myRect
>   will make it go down to 2 since I call
>   release on the origin in dealloc().
>   But then, when does autorelease take
>   effect?

An `autorelease` is simply a delayed `release` that kicks in when the containing pool is `drain`ed.  So, in your case, the object will be deallocated when `[pool drain];` is executed.

Comment: Good info. Didn't know the getter called a retain/autorelease.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's documentation on `-retainCount`:

> **Important:** This method is typically of
>   no value in debugging memory
>   management issues. Because any number
>   of framework objects may have retained
>   an object in order to hold references
>   to it, while at the same time
>   autorelease pools may be holding any
>   number of deferred releases on an
>   object, it is very unlikely that you
>   can get useful information from this
>   method.